# Not able to transport OData

Tags: sap-basis, sap-gateway

I tried to move OData service from DEV to QAS system via Transport Request but even after TR movement still some services are not moved...

I again deleted service in DEV and after (`/n/iwfnd/maint_service`) reactivation captured services in new TR still after moving TR service is not available in QAS.

What should I do to transport OData services? I can't add them directly in QAS... QAS is not modifiable by me.

Comment: What did you exactly add in your transport request? What did you exactly check in QAS?

Comment: I am trying to add odata service for apps which I got from sap reference library..I am trying to add that odata into transport request and then need to move it to qas ..added in transaction/n/iwfnd/maint_service

Comment: How do you make sure that your transported service is not available in QAS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have:

- Package SAP Gateway
- Model Metadata SAP Gateway
- Service Groups Metadata
- ICF Service Table Contents
  in the "Objects" tab of your transport request.

Also, note that due to security ICF Nodes are transported in an inactive state by default.